# How to map mock mvc GET call into java POJO?

Tags: testing, spring-boot, jackson, mockmvc

I have a rest controller method that returns an object `CompositeObject` that contains within it several other objects and structures (Maps and Lists). I want to write a test that tests whether the rest get call returns that object along with the fields (even if the values for those fields are null), but I don't know how to map the response of the mock mvc call below:

```
String response = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/getclassdata?classCode=cs").accept("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

This test works fine, however I want to check whether the returned JSON is an object I am interested in (`CompositeObject`) as well as make sure  that it contains all the required fields. How can I test for this? Is there something in the testing framework that is similar to `instanceof`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can read Json response to POJO using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/example-endpoint")).andReturn();

ExampleResponse parsedResponse = mapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray(), ExampleResponse.class);
```